# Are the stellar history (XDR) files available in other regions or on other cloud providers

Tags: stellar-core, xdr, history

Most of the documentation or configuration info I have seen reference the history.stellar.org bucket on AWS S3 as the official source of history data. This bucket appears to be in the eu-west-1 (Ireland) region.

Are these files also replicated to S3 buckets in other regions that may be closer to a given node? Are there "official" data sources on Azure or GCP as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have any other official history archived besides `history.stellar.org`, although we do plan to add more at some point in the future.

We're also hoping others will step up and host history mirrors to better decentralize.  In my non-company opinion, I'd prefer the network to be in a state such that the "official" history archives are not necessary.

disclosure: I work at the SDF